# Crud com tabelas relacionadas no spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação **java**, utilizando **spring mvc**.
E em uma funcionalidade *CRUD*, tenho uma tela de cadastro de Incidentes. Nessa tela, tenho os campos mapeados conforme a entidade Incidente.java. Porem na tela de cadastro eu tenho mais campos que não fazem parte dessa entidade, faz parte de uma outra entidade.
Qual seria a melhor maneira de solucionar isso?

Modelo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Classe, model, Incidente:

```
public class Incidente {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "CD_TICKET")
    private Integer ticket;

    @Column(name = "DESC_RESUMIDA")
    private String descricaoResumida;
}
```

Classe model Empresa:

```
public class Empresa {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NM_EMPRESA")
    private String nome;
}
```

Classe model Impacto:

```
public class Impacto implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Serial Version
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_INCIDENTE")
    private Incidente incidente;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SERVICO")
    private Servico servico;

}
```

Classe model Serviço:

```
public class Servico {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NM_SERVICO")
    private String nome;
}
```

**Obs:** Lembrando que, na tela de cadastro de incidentes, eu tenho um combobox (select/dropdowlist), dos serviços, e também de empresas. Nessa tela eu devo poder informar os impactos que tem esse incidente, exemplo:

Na tela de cadastro do incidente 1, vou informar: 
*

```
incidente 1 - impacta o servico A
incidente 1 - impacta o servico C
incidente 1 - impacta o servico J
```

*

Isso vou salvar na tabela de impacto:
*

```
incidente 1 - servico A
incidente 1 - servico C
incidente 1 - servico J
incidente 2 - servico A
incidente 3 - servico D
```

etc...*